# Why does my Plotly Graph show multiple duplicates of Data?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

So i've written a Python/Pandas Script which takes multiple CSVs, reads out data (Timestamp and Energy Field in my case) 
and displays the daily yield and the monthly sum in a plotly graph.
So far so good. Now i realized that my Plotly Graph is displaying the *wrong scale/axe dimensions*.
 During debugging i discovered that my script is also writting multiple entries in that data-list.
To test the funcitonality of the plotly lib, i have made some dummy entries and it does just what you expect from it.

**My Chart should look like this:**
[image]

**But instead looks like this:**
[image: On the individual Bars you can see the there are multiple entries of the same data]

**So this is the relevant code:**

```
# Transform Timestamp column into datetime
combined_csv['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(combined_csv.Timestamp)

# Read out first entry of every day of every month
combined_csv = combined_csv.resample('D', on='Timestamp')['HtmDht_Energy'].agg(['first']).reset_index()

# To get the yield of day i have to subtract day 2 HtmDht_Energy - day 1 HtmDht_Energy
combined_csv["Tagesertrag"] = combined_csv["first"].diff()
combined_csv.Tagesertrag = combined_csv.Tagesertrag.round()
# To get monthly sum of dailyYield
combined_csv["Monatssumme"] = combined_csv.groupby([combined_csv.Timestamp.dt.year, combined_csv.Timestamp.dt.month]).Tagesertrag.transform("sum")

combined_csv.Monatssumme = combined_csv.Monatssumme.round()
#
# Convert Timestamp into needed format
combined_csv['Tag'] = combined_csv.Timestamp.dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
combined_csv['Monat'] = combined_csv.Timestamp.dt.month_name()
# combined_csv['Year'] = combined_csv.Timestamp.dt.month_name().drop_duplicates(keep = False, inplace = True)

# Tagesertrag Chart New
daily_data = [go.Bar(x=combined_csv['Tag'], y=combined_csv['Tagesertrag'])]
dailyYield = go.Figure(daily_data)

# Monatssumme Chart New
print(combined_csv['Monat'])
print(combined_csv['Monatssumme'])
monthly_data = [go.Bar(x=combined_csv['Monat'], y=combined_csv['Monatssumme'])]
monthlySum = go.Figure(monthly_data)

#Test Case
#test_month = ['jan', 'feb', 'march', 'april']
#test_month_values = [20000, 60000, 140000, 12345]
#print(test_month)
#print(test_month_values)
#monthly_data_2 = [go.Bar(x=test_month, y=test_month_values)]
#monthlySum_2 = go.Figure(monthly_data_2)


# Export HTML File
plotly.offline.plot(dailyYield, filename="DailyYieldReport.html")
plotly.offline.plot(monthlySum, filename="MonthlySumReport.html")
```

When i print "Monatssumme" (=MonthlySum) i get 118 objects, which doesn't seem right to me.

```
**0       20099.0
1       20099.0
2       20099.0
3       20099.0
4       20099.0
         ...   
113    194681.0
114    194681.0
115    194681.0
116    194681.0
117    194681.0
Name: Monatssumme, Length: 118, dtype: float64**
```

I think my Problem has something todo with the multiple data-entries.
All the Calculations get back the right numbers but they are displayed multiple, which then messes up the scale of the plot.
Do i need to "drop them" off somehow?

Comment: Before drawing the first graph, the data was not aggregated into months, so the graph would have been a pile of the same values. So, before drawing the graph, we need the following code. `combined_csv = combined_csv.groupby(['Monat','Monatssumme']).first().sort_values('Tag', ascending=True)`

Comment: @r-beginners First of all thanks for your suggestion but I get an KeyError Monat when i do this, i have positioned your code after the declaration of Monat & Monatssumme of course.

Comment: I tried to run it in [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11rtX51ImsJJoOyPeo73T9y9ENAlyF6lC?usp=sharing). Please check. If you confirm this, it will remove the comment containing the link.

Comment: Ok so i see that it works in colab and i tried it on my site, the only thing i changed was on the resample line i had timestamp and you have Date, when i do this i get another KeyError which says: The grouper name Date is not found, i think we're really close - can you help me please

Comment: I changed the Date to Timestamp, can you please check it?

Comment: The daily yield is working correctly, i think i falsly explained my problem. It's about the MonthlySum and not the dailyYield. Since i saw that you changed the daily_data column.

Comment: For month we look at the columns "Monat" and "Monatssumme" or am i missing something?

Comment: The data just before graphing the monthly totals must be aggregated by month, and if it is aggregated, it is fine.